# Work Visa and Work Permit Exemption for German citizen in Turkey for the duration of one week

Tags: visas, turkey, business-travel, working-visas, german-citizens

I am a little bit unclear about some specific visa requirements for a German citizen visiting Turkey on behalf of a German employer providing services to a Turkish customer for the duration of one week.

My employer sells complex electronic systems all over the world. Specifically, in Turkey, via a Turkish partner, who buy systems and services from us and re-sell them to the local end-customer. In November, I am scheduled to travel to Turkey for one week for the purpose of configuring such a system.

It is my understanding that I cannot use the visa-free program, since this is not a tourist or commerce activity. I will need a Work Visa. It seems that I qualify for a Work Permit Exemption ("For the purpose of installation,maintenance and repair of machinery and equipment imported to Turkey, providing training for their utilization […]").

Is that understanding correct?

In that case, I will have to apply for a Work Visa at my local consulate, and for a Work Permit Exemption at the Ministry of Labor (which I can do through the local consulate at the same time as the visa application). As supporting documents, I will need:

- Biometric photo
- Hotel booking
- Flight reservation
- Supporting documents from employer, including at least:

  - purpose of visit
  - date of visit
  - place of work

I could not find any specific requirements for proof-of-funds, nor any vaccination requirements.

Is that correct? Did I overlook something important (for example, might I actually still qualify for a visa-free entry)?

If we want to get *really* technical, then our partner received training on how to configure such a system. So, they *should* be able to perform the configuration by themselves, in which case I would only be advising them, which then would qualify as a meeting or consultation and allow me visa-free entry. However, I do fear that this distinction might be lost on an immigration officer at the airport, and so I do not want to pursue this line of reasoning.

Comment: Looking through the [official web site](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa), it certainly seems so. Which is very strange; most countries where I have ever looked permit this sort of activity on business visits.

Comment: I noticed that my question has received two close votes because "Questions about immigration or moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others) are off-topic. Our sister site, Expatriates Stack Exchange might be a better place to ask." I was not aware that a one-week configuration job constitutes as "immigration" or "moving for extended periods of time" by the standards of this web site, I am sorry. Honestly, I know people who go on holiday for two weeks at a time, is that also off-topic here?

Comment: I think the question may be misunderstood by people who only read the title. This is more of a business visit, short in nature. Well within what is dealt with here!

Comment: @Ozzy: I did actually tag the question with [tag:business-travel], but the tag was [edited out](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/144922/2). Should I put it back in?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That text is also displayed as part of the pre-application, although at your link it is better formatted and more readable. Interestingly, the article 55 in law 4817 that is referenced in that text does not exist (law 4817 only has 37 articles), plus law 4817 [was apparently replaced with a newer one](http://bakerxchange.com/rv/ff0029b582f2492ea1ae8d9bba4fb41d8374cf4c) and isn't even valid anymore. Methinks the best course of action would be to call the consulate tomorrow and simply explain the situation to them and ask for the correct visa.