# Single or Multiple Entry for a Turkish Work Visa if I don't know how often I will need to go?

Tags: visas, turkey, multiple-entry, working-visas, german-citizens

This question is related to: [Work Visa and Work Permit Exemption for German citizen in Turkey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144922/20425). Quick summary: I need to go to Turkey for one week in order to configure a system that my employer sold through our Turkish partner.

At the moment, only one visit of one week is planned. However, it is somewhat likely that updates to the system will need to be performed at some point, and at least for major updates, our local partner might need assistance. Considering that I will be the one who knows the system best, it is likely that I will be the one sent to assist with such updates.

So, while at the moment, only one visit is planned, does it make sense to apply for a multiple entry visa, even if I don't know yet when or even if I will go there next?